# Oracle built-in functions metadata

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, aggregate-functions

Is there a way to get metadata for the Oracle built-in aggeregate and other functions such as `AVG, STDDEV, SQRT,` etc.?
I need to know object id and arguments meta.

In the `SYS.ALL_OBJECTS` view I couldn't find anything useful. I also tried to search in `SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS` view by object_name.

Is there views or tables with built-in functions with data similar to `SYS.ALL_OBJECTS` and `SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have tagged Oracle 10g, [but from what I can find](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_sqltypes.htm#CIHEHJIB), you'll need Oracle 11g r1 to find out metadata on built-in SQL functions.

> You can see metadata for SQL built-in functions with the dynamic performance views `V$SQLFN_METADATA` (which has general metadata) and `V$SQLFN_ARG_METADATA` (which has metadata about arguments).
>
> You can join these views on the column FUNCID. For functions with unlimited arguments, such as LEAST and GREATEST, V$SQLFN_ARG_METADATA has only one row for each repeating argument.

Answer (score 3):

The straight SQL (non-aggregation) built-in functions can be described in Oracle10g in SQL*Plus by issuing `describe SYS.STANDARD`.

```
SQL> desc sys.standard;
FUNCTION  SYS$DSINTERVALSUBTRACT RETURNS INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LEFT                           TIMESTAMP               IN
 RIGHT                          TIMESTAMP               IN
FUNCTION  SYS$DSINTERVALSUBTRACT RETURNS INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LEFT                           TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE IN
 RIGHT                          TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE IN
```

... snip for brevity

```
FUNCTION VSIZE RETURNS NUMBER
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 E                              DATE                    IN
FUNCTION VSIZE RETURNS NUMBER
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 E                              VARCHAR2                IN
FUNCTION XOR RETURNS BOOLEAN
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LEFT                           BOOLEAN                 IN
 RIGHT                          BOOLEAN                 IN
```