# How to write a function only used in the where clause that evaluates to true without a comparison operator?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, where-clause, conditional-statements

**My question is:**
In Oracle regexp_like works alone in the where clause without having to compare to 1 or 0 or a string. The function can only be called when evaluating something in a case statement or the where clause. Since it can't be described (tried searching the data dictionary for it) I'm wondering how to write a function that works the same way.

**For example:**

```
function is_prod
returns boolean
is 
  l_var boolean := false;
begin
  if sys_context('userenv','db_unique_name') = '"PROD_SERVER"' then
    l_var := true;
  end if;
return l_var;
end;
```

That function compiles, but cannot be used in a SQL statement like the following:

```
select *
from table t
where is_prod
```

Because I get the following error: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator.

Comparing it to a number or true doesn't work either.

**Where can I find the code base for regexp_like or what do I need to do to make this work like regexp_like?**

Note: I've looked around for several hours and found that Oracle's regexp functions are actually java calls, but that means they still need a pl/sql wrapper.

Comment: +1 I would be quite interested to see the answer to this, but at the same time I have to ask myself at what point does the time spent solving this problem outweigh the time spent writing "= 1". I expect the answer is in about 10 years time.

Comment: @GarethD Yes, I've wondered the same thing. I'd love to see PL/SQL act more like an object oriented language than a procedural language :) And, we know it can be done because of the example he gave (`regexp_like`) can do it.

Comment: `REGEXP_LIKE` is a [condition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/conditions.htm), not a function.

Comment: Strange example.  A where clause generally limits rows returned, not access.  Here you seem to want to limit access to the table (if the env is not PROD, then return 0 rows).  Seems you really want Oracle VPD access control ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/vpd.htm#CIHFAJDC ).  Once VPD policy is setup, it will launch the policy function for you transparently.

Answer (score 9):

Basically, oracle has a boolean datatype **only** for PLSQL. 
So, as long as you stay in plsql you can use them but not in SQL.

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#CJACJGBG):

> Because SQL has no data type equivalent to BOOLEAN, you cannot:
>
> - Assign a BOOLEAN value to a database table column
> - Select or fetch the value of a database table column into a BOOLEAN
>     variable
> - Use a BOOLEAN value in a SQL statement, SQL function, or PL/SQL
>     function invoked from a SQL statement

If you want to find metadata about built-in functions, then maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9942585/1083652) can help.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Doesn't work like that. the where statement always looks for a function/column where something is. even if the function works you still have to tell the where statement which value you want True or False

I haven't used Oracle SQL, but looking at what you have there I think that if you write it like this

```
  select *
  from table t
  where is_prod = True
```

it will work, if you change the Variable type in your function to something like a Varchar(5) or something similar.

you are actually asking that function to look at several records, so when you have it like you do it acts like a Select Statement and not like a where statement.  it will give the value of the function but not filter the where.
it will look like a column with `true` or `false` values.

When you use the function in a `Where` statement like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE is_Prod
```

it's like saying:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE Column1
```

you have to clarify for the `WHERE` Statement

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE Column1 = 'blue' or is_Prod = 'false'
```

in C# you can use a String as a boolean, if it is null it returns false

in SQL Server it comes out like this

```
Column2 IS NULL
```

you still need an operator

*** Separator ***

as I don't use Oracle I was unable to test this.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

REGEXP_LIKE  is a like Statement.  so it uses a comparison operator.

you could probably write a regexp in a like statement, although I am sure that it is time consuming and monotonous so they made a function that does it for you.

in other words you still have to use the '= whatever' on the function that you created.

Comment: No, Oracle SQL doesn't have a boolean type (though PL/SQL does), so you can't use a function that returns a boolean. You can of course fake it with 0/1, T/F rather than a true boolean, but I think that's what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: either way you write it you have to add the = 'something'

Comment: But the `= 'something'` is what the OP is looking to get rid of because you don't need `regexp_like('123','12') = TRUE` or something. That's the purpose of the question.

Comment: SQL Doesn't work like that.  the where statement always looks for a function/column where something is.  even if the function works you still have to tell the where statement which value you want True or False

Comment: @Malione, your last comment would look good as the first part of your answer. That way your answer reflects the question and it's a little more constructive :)